# cutting stock optimization/waste minimize in r using lpsolve/lpsolveapi

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

I am having a tough time understanding the how to formulate code to a cutting stock problem.  I have searched the web extensively and I see a lot of theory but no actual examples.

The majority of query results point to the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

13 patterns to be produced, with required amounts indicated alongside.
The machine produces by default a 5600 width piece to be cut into widths below.  Goal is to minimize waste.

```
  Widths/Required amount
1380    22
1520    25
1560    12
1710    14
1820    18
1880    18
1930    20
2000    10
2050    12
2100    14
2140    16
2150    18
2200    20
```

Would someone show me how to formulate this solution in R with lpsolve/lpsolve API?

```
  stock=5600
  widths=c(1380,1520,1560,1710,1820,1880,1930,2000,2050,2100,2140,2150,2200)
  required=c(22,25,12,14,18,18,20,10,12,14,16,18,20)

 library(lpSolveAPI)




 ...
 solve(lprec)
 get.variables(lprec)
```

Comment: Are you able to provide details on how you ended up doing this?  Code to generate patterns, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model it as a Mixed Integer Problem and solve it using various techniques. Of course to generate variables (i.e. a valid pattern of widths) you need to use a suitable column generation method.

Have a look at this C++ project: https://code.google.com/p/cspsol

cspsol is based on GLPK API library, uses column generation and branch & bound to solve the MIP. It may give you some hints about how to do it in R.
Good luck !